# why apache2 virtual host overridden by default

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-20.04

(I'm kinda new to apache). I want to serve a wiki from my server `myserver.com`. I've created a DNS record for `wiki.myserver.com`, which can be reached by ssh/http/ping (so, it exists). I have default 000-default.conf, and the following wiki.myserver.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wiki"
    ServerName wiki.myserver.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/wiki/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/wiki.myserver.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/wiki.myserver.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server wiki.myserver.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost wiki.myserver.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost wiki.myserver.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wiki.myserver.com.conf:1)
```

Surfing to http://myserver.com results in default apache2 index page, as expected.
Surfing to http://myserver.com/wiki results in wiki page, as expected (I guess).
Surfing to http://wiki.myserver.com results in default apache2 index page, where I expect the wiki page.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find a difference between my setup and what is generally instructed on the internet.
Can you help by suggesting some ways for debugging?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just stupid; I had set my servername in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf` to the wrong default. It's working just fine now.